# How to "source ~/.bashrc" automatically when connect to remote

Tags: ssh, bashrc, source, sshpass

I need to create some aliases on remote Ubuntu and enable them on ssh-connection. So I defined aliases in ~/.bashrc file (on that remote Ubuntu).

Now when I do

```
ssh root@<Remote IP>
source ~/.bashrc
```

I can use those aliases... But instead of do `source ~/.bashrc` manually each time I want to automate that as well. So I tried

```
sshpass -p 'none' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<Remote IP> -t 'source ~/.bashrc'
```

... but the connection is closed

if I do

```
sshpass -p none ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<Remote IP> -t 'ssh root@<Remote IP>; source ~/.bashrc'
```

then it's not disconnected, but no possibility to input commands - no reaction from terminal on input

So how to connect to remote host and load ~/.bashrc in the same command?

Comment: Don't use root, use the admin. Works the same but the config will be in your normal home and it will source your bashrc as it wil get parsed by (I believe /etc/profile(?))

Comment: I'm using root cause it requires no password while admin user requires password which I don't know... But do you mean that if I do `ssh admin@<IP>` then `source /home/admin/.bashrc` will be automatically executed?

Comment: As @steeldriver suggests below, you can add that source command to the file `/root/.profile`

Comment: no it does  not. i have tens of ssh conections I do not need a password for using the admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `ssh root@<Remote IP>`, you will get root's login shell which (assuming it's bash) will load /root/.profile (or /root/.bash_profile if it exists).

So probably the cleanest solution is to make sure that file sources the .bashrc file (giving root's login shell the same environment as their non-login interactive shell).

The default Ubuntu `~/.profile` (copied from `/etc/skel/`) does this automatically:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Also, maybe specifying a command after SSH disconnects the session immediately after executing the command on the remote host?

Comment: I didn't find`/home/root/.profile` existing. But creating the file and inserting those lines to `~/.profile` seem to do the trick. Thanks

Comment: he said `/root/.profile`

Comment: There is no `/root` folder but `/home/root` only

Comment: By default, Ubuntu uses `/root` for the root account's home directory, but the system administrator may have changed that